# Build Times VSCode are higher that Visual Studio

Tags: c++, cmake

I made an effort to stop using Visual Studio and instead making a C++ project using CMake and VSCode. Now the build times are 10 times slower...

My own code is relatively small bust has dependencies on a lot of libraries that are placed in the precompiled header.

I am in a position waiting a very long time until something is compiled before it was
8 seconds now it is 40 seconds and sometimes goes up to 2 minutes. Any minor code changed is really nightmare. The problem is that I do not know where to start optimizing it. I enable precompiled headers which reduces the speed from 2 min to 38 seconds, but is nowhere near as 8 seconds.

Can someone give me an advice how can I start finding out what library is causing such long delays?

Several answers to comments below:

```
1. I am comparing "native" Visual Studio project vs the CMake project.
2. I am using MSVC
3. Parallel build reduces the time from 38 to 24 seconds "--parallel 4"
```

My main CMakeLists looks like this:

```
########################################################################
#
# CONFIGURE THE PROJECT
#
########################################################################

###############################################################################
#EXECUTABLE LINK HEADER ONLY DIRECTORY
###############################################################################
SET(BUILD_MY_PROJECTS "" CACHE STRING "Build Project")
if (BUILD_MY_PROJECTS)
  message(AUTHOR_WARNING "BUILD_MY_PROJECTS_" ${BUILD_MY_PROJECTS})



  ###############################################################################
  # CREATE EXE
  ###############################################################################
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp 
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/wood/include/wood_joint.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/wood/include/wood_test.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/wood/include/wood_xml.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/wood/include/cgal_mesh_boolean.cpp"
  ) 


  ###############################################################################
  # LIBRARIES
  ###############################################################################

  ###############################################################################
  # OPENGL
  ###############################################################################
  find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

  ###############################################################################
  # CDT
  ###############################################################################
  # set(CDT_INC
  # "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/CDT.h"
  # "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/CDT.hpp"
  # "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/CDTUtils.h"
  # "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/CDTUtils.hpp"
  # "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/KDTree.h"
  # "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/LocatorKDTree.h"
  # "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/predicates.h"
  # "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/remove_at.hpp"
  # )

  # set(CDT_SRC
  # "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/src/CDT.cpp"
  # )

  # add_library(CDT STATIC ${CDT_INC} ${CDT_SRC}  )
  # target_include_directories(CDT  PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/") #link headers to clipper library


  ###############################################################################
  # CLIPPER
  ###############################################################################
  set(CLIPPER2_INC
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/include/clipper2/clipper.core.h"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/include/clipper2/clipper.engine.h"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/include/clipper2/clipper.h"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/include/clipper2/clipper.minkowski.h"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/include/clipper2/clipper.offset.h"
 )

  set(CLIPPER2_SRC
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/src/clipper.engine.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/src/clipper.offset.cpp"
  )

  add_library(Clipper2 STATIC ${CLIPPER2_INC} ${CLIPPER2_SRC}  )
  target_include_directories(Clipper2  PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/include/") #link headers to clipper library

  ###############################################################################
  # IMGUI
  ###############################################################################

  list(APPEND IMGUI_INC 
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/glfw/include/"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/backends/"
  )

  set(IMGUI_SRC

  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/imgui_demo.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/imgui_tables.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/imgui.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp"
  )

  add_library(imgui STATIC ${IMGUI_INC} ${IMGUI_SRC}  )
  target_include_directories(imgui  PUBLIC ${IMGUI_INC}) #link headers to clipper library

  ###############################################################################
  # STB
  ###############################################################################
  set(STB_INC
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/stb/stb_image.h"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/stb/stb_image_write.h"
 )

  set(STB_SRC
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/src/stb/stb_image.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/src/stb/stb_image_write.cpp"
  )

  add_library(STB STATIC ${STB_INC} ${STB_SRC}  )
  target_include_directories(STB  PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/stb/") #link headers to clipper library

  ###############################################################################
  # CGAL
  ###############################################################################
  #target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/lib/" ) # WINDOWS
  if(COMPILER_NINJA)
    target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/" )
  else()
    target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/lib/" )
  endif()

  
  if(NOT COMPILER_NINJA)
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD        # Adds a post-build event to MyTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different  # which executes "cmake - E copy_if_different..."
          "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.dll"      # <--this is in-file
          "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release")                 # <--this is out-file path

    add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD        # Adds a post-build event to MyTest
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different  # which executes "cmake - E copy_if_different..."
          "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.dll"      # <--this is in-file
          "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release")                 # <--this is out-file path
  endif()

  ###############################################################################
  # BOOST
  ###############################################################################

  ###############################################################################
  # EIGEN
  ###############################################################################





  ###############################################################################
  # LINK HEADERS TO EXE
  # check path:
  # message(AUTHOR_WARNING "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/stb")
  ###############################################################################
  list(APPEND petras_include_paths 
  #my_code
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/stb/"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/pipe/"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/opengl/"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/viewer/include/imgui/"
  #cdt
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cdt/CDT/include/"
  #clipper
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/include/"
  #imgui
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/imgui/backends/"
  #glfw
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/glfw/include/"
  #glad
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/glad/include/"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/glad/include/glad"
  #glm
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/glm/"
  #assimp
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/assimp/include/"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/assimp/contrib/zlib/"# WINDOWS
  #boost
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/boost/include/boost-1_78/"
  #eigen
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/eigen/"
  #cgal
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/include"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/include"
  #"C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/" #GCC

  )


  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${petras_include_paths}>") #header for the library

  ###############################################################################
  # LINK LIBRARIES TO EXE, STATIC LIBRARIES PATHS MUST BE AT THE END
  ###############################################################################
  if(COMPILER_NINJA)
      message(STATUS "COMPILER_NINJA ON")
      target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
      Clipper2 
      opengl32 
      imgui 
      glfw3 
      glad 
      assimp 
      stb 
      zlibstatic 
      gmp
      mpfr
      ) #gmp mpfr link library | zlibstatic WINDOWS

  else()
    message(STATUS "COMPILER_NINJA OFF")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
      Clipper2 
      opengl32 
      imgui 
      glfw3 
      glad 
      assimp 
      stb 
      zlibstatic 
      libgmp-10
      libmpfr-4
    ) #gmp mpfr link library | zlibstatic WINDOWS
  endif()

  ###############################################################################
  # GLFW
  ###############################################################################
  target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/glfw/src/" )

  ###############################################################################
  # GLAD
  ###############################################################################
  target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/glad/")

  ###############################################################################
  # ASSIMP
  ###############################################################################
  target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/assimp/lib/" )
  target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/assimp/contrib/zlib/" ) # WINDOWS

  ###############################################################################
  # STB
  ###############################################################################
  target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/" )

  ###############################################################################
  # PCH support
  ###############################################################################
  #option(KDV_BUILD_USING_PCH "Build using pre-compile header support" ON)
  #if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 3.16 AND KDV_BUILD_USING_PCH) # support for PCHs in CMake was added in 3.16
  message(STATUS "Compiling using pre-compiled header support")
  target_precompile_headers(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE stdafx.h) # With PUBLIC they will be used by targets using this target
  #target_precompile_headers(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE   "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/CMakeFiles/compas_wood.dir/Release/cmake_pch.hxx")
  set(CMAKE_PCH_INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATES ON)
```

If that helps following is the verbose compilation process:

```
Executing task in folder compas_wood:  cmake  --build c:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ -v --config Release --parallel 6 &&  c:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\Release\wood.exe 

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.0+ae57d105c for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10/26/2022 9:02:28 PM.
     1>Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" on node 1 (defaul
       t targets).
     1>Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building " 
       C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default ta 
       rgets).
     2>InitializeBuildStatus:
         Creating "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
       CustomBuild:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
       FinalizeBuildStatus:
         Deleting file "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
         Touching "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
     2>Done Building Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (d 
       efault targets).
     1>Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "
       C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\Clipper2.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targ 
       ets).
     3>InitializeBuildStatus:
         Creating "Clipper2.dir\Release\Clipper2.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
       CustomBuild:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
     1>Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "
       C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\imgui.vcxproj" (4) on node 3 (default targets 
       ).
     4>InitializeBuildStatus:
         Creating "imgui.dir\Release\imgui.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
     1>Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building " 
       C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\STB.vcxproj" (6) on node 2 (default targets). 
     6>InitializeBuildStatus:
         Creating "STB.dir\Release\STB.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
     4>CustomBuild:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
     6>CustomBuild:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
     4>ClCompile:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
     6>ClCompile:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
     4>Lib:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
     6>Lib:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
     4>Lib:
         imgui.vcxproj -> C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\Release\imgui.lib
     6>Lib:
         STB.vcxproj -> C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\Release\STB.lib
     3>ClCompile:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
       Lib:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
         Clipper2.vcxproj -> C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\Release\Clipper2.lib    
       FinalizeBuildStatus:
         Deleting file "Clipper2.dir\Release\Clipper2.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
         Touching "Clipper2.dir\Release\Clipper2.tlog\Clipper2.lastbuildstate".
     3>Done Building Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\Clipper2.vcxproj" (def 
       ault targets).
     6>FinalizeBuildStatus:
         Deleting file "STB.dir\Release\STB.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
         Touching "STB.dir\Release\STB.tlog\STB.lastbuildstate".
     4>FinalizeBuildStatus:
         Deleting file "imgui.dir\Release\imgui.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
         Touching "imgui.dir\Release\imgui.tlog\imgui.lastbuildstate".
     6>Done Building Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\STB.vcxproj" (default 
       targets).
     4>Done Building Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\imgui.vcxproj" (defaul 
       t targets).
     1>Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building " 
       C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\wood.vcxproj" (5) on node 4 (default targets) 
       .
     5>InitializeBuildStatus:
         Creating "wood.dir\Release\wood.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
       CustomBuild:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
       ClCompile:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
         C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /IC:\ 
         IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\viewer\include /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\sup 
         er_build\compas_wood\viewer\include\stb /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\viewer\incl 
         ude\pipe /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\viewer\include\opengl /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\S 
         oftware\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\viewer\include\imgui /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\ 
         compas_wood\build_win\install\cdt\CDT\include /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build 
         _win\install\clipper_2\CPP\Clipper2Lib\include /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\buil 
         d_win\install\imgui /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\install\imgui\backend 
         s /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\install\glfw\include /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code 
         \Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\install\glad\include /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\ 
         super_build\compas_wood\build_win\install\glad\include\glad /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\com 
         pas_wood\build_win\install\glm /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\install\as 
         simp\include /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\install\assimp\contrib\zlib  
         /I"C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\install\boost\include\boost-1_78" /IC:\I 
         BOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\install\eigen /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\C 
         MAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\install\cgal\include /IC:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\com 
         pas_wood\build_win\install\cgal\auxiliary\gmp\include /nologo /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /O2 /Ob2 /D _MBCS /D W
         IN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope  
         /Zc:inline /std:c++20 /Yu"C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/CMakeFiles/wood.d 
         ir/Release/cmake_pch.hxx" /Fp"C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/wood.dir/Rele 
         ase/cmake_pch.pch" /Fo"wood.dir\Release\\" /Fd"wood.dir\Release\vc143.pdb" /external:W1 /Gd /TP /FIC:/IBOIS57/_Co 
         de/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/CMakeFiles/wood.dir/Release/cmake_pch.hxx /errorReport:qu 
         eue C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\main.cpp
         main.cpp
       Link:
         C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERROR
         REPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\Release\wood.exe" /INCRE 
         MENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/install/cgal/aux 
         iliary/gmp/lib /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/install/cgal/auxili 
         ary/gmp/lib/Release /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/install/glfw/s 
         rc /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/install/glfw/src/Release /LIBPA 
         TH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/install/glad /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/S 
         oftware/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/install/glad/Release /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/C 
         MAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/install/assimp/lib /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_buil 
         d/compas_wood/build_win/install/assimp/lib/Release /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compa 
         s_wood/build_win/install/assimp/contrib/zlib /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood 
         /build_win/install/assimp/contrib/zlib/Release /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wo 
         od/build_win /LIBPATH:C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/Release Release\Clipp 
         er2.lib opengl32.lib Release\imgui.lib glfw3.lib glad.lib assimp.lib stb.lib zlibstatic.lib "libgmp-10.lib" "libm 
         pfr-4.lib" kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.li 
         b advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:"C:/IBOIS57/_Code 
         /Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/Release/wood.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE  
         /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build_win/Release/wood.lib" /MACHI 
         NE:X64  /machine:x64 wood.dir\Release\cmake_pch.obj
         wood.dir\Release\main.obj
         wood.dir\Release\wood_joint.obj
         wood.dir\Release\wood_test.obj
         wood.dir\Release\wood_xml.obj
         wood.dir\Release\cgal_mesh_boolean.obj
         wood.vcxproj -> C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\Release\wood.exe
       PostBuildEvent:
         setlocal
         "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_if_different C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compa 
         s_wood/build_win/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.dll C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/com 
         pas_wood/build_win/Release
         if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
         :cmEnd
         endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
         :cmErrorLevel
         exit /b %1
         :cmDone
         if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
         setlocal
         "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy_if_different C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compa 
         s_wood/build_win/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.dll C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/com 
         pas_wood/build_win/Release
         if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
         :cmEnd
         endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
         :cmErrorLevel
         exit /b %1
         :cmDone
         if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
         :VCEnd
       FinalizeBuildStatus:
         Deleting file "wood.dir\Release\wood.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
         Touching "wood.dir\Release\wood.tlog\wood.lastbuildstate".
     5>Done Building Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\wood.vcxproj" (default 
        targets).
     1>InitializeBuildStatus:
         Creating "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
       CustomBuild:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
       FinalizeBuildStatus:
         Deleting file "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
         Touching "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\ALL_BUILD.lastbuildstate".
     1>Done Building Project "C:\IBOIS57\_Code\Software\CPP\CMAKE\super_build\compas_wood\build_win\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (de 
       fault targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:24.45
```

Comment: When comparing, do you mean a CMake project opened (not generated) in Visual Studio vs the same CMake project opened in Visual Studio Code OR a "native" Visual Studio project vs the CMake project?

Comment: Are you building the cmake project with more than a single thread? (`cmake --build ... --parallel 4`. Also I wouldn't go all the way immediately: Try using the visual studio generator first and work with the VS (non-code) IDE and check, if the compilation times are as bad...

Comment: What compiler? MinGW is notoriously slow, and Clang is almost as fast as MSVC.

Comment: Btw: why are there so many sources in your ***binary*** directory? If you rely on specific files to be available in the cmake build directory before, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. Usually the binary directories should contain only files that are generated during the cmake configuration or build.

Comment: I added edits to the first two comments (MSVC, Visual Studio vs CMake comparison, tested parallel). @fabian Do you mean this line ?  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp 
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/wood/include/wood_joint.cpp" ...
These cpp files are quite small in size. I suspect the libraries.

Comment: Nope, I'm not referring to anything taking sources from the source dir, but those that are taking them from the build ("binary") dirs. In particular the stuff in the following variables: `CLIPPER2_INC`, `CLIPPER2_SRC`, `IMGUI_SRC`. During reconfiguration cmake can place quite a lot of files in the binary directories, so it's often hard to tell, if there are files that could be overwritten by cmake.

Comment: Also the fact that you're including these post build scripts for copying the files to somewhere in the build dir tells me that you may be setting up different potentially overlapping build dirs which will almost certainly result in problems. If you want to put the build results somewhere. I recommend using [`install()` commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html). Those automatically take care of the copying for you, if you run `cmake --install` and allow you to specify a default install root via `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` cache variable or overwriting this via `--prefix`

Comment: Do you think, if I would build library clipper as you indicated by "sources files" as a static library first and then link with only headers, would it increase the build time? The reason why those libraries are in build is because I am using ExternalProject_Add before I compile my code (just once on a fresh computer). I wish there would be some good explanation  about each step of compilation process. E.G. how much time my individual libraries takes time to compute. One thing I must do it for sure is to splt cmake file for 3rd party library compilation and actual code compilation.

Comment: @fabian if I compile separately libraries with "add_library" and "target_include_directories" in a separate cmakelist, how you would reference those compiled static libraries to exe project in a separate cmakelists? Instead of e.g. llibrary name in "target_link_libraries" i must specify full path or a prefix? I will never modify those 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think every commenter gave good comments to optimize the code.
I added:

- parallel
- split files to .cpp files and .h, inline methods increases compilation time, it is a fact
- never compile static libraries in the same cmakelists as for building exe, do it in to steps
- the biggest problem was, that I was using a .h file with hard coded data-set. I will read data from files instead of doing this ‍♂️, this added 10-12 sec of compilation time (does not matter if this is part of precompiled header or not...):
- now the time is back to 8 seconds
  [image]